# For any consecutive natural numbers $a_1,a_2$ are there infinitely many primes $p,q$ such that: $a_1<\dfrac{p}{q}<a_2$?

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, real-numbers

**Progress**:

> Let $a_1,a_2$ consecutive natural numbers; prove or disprove the infinitude of distinct prime pair $p,q$ which satidfies: $a_1<\dfrac{p}{q}<a_2$

The most challenging part of the statement is the *"infinitude"* of such $p,q$, as primes become less common as they become larger. I tried several values for $a_1,a_2$, and what I found is that as $a_1,a_2$ grow larger, the prime pair $p,q$ gets hard to find.

As usual I would really appreciate any opinion or insight and an elementary proof or counter example. Thanks.

Comment: You could've just used $a_1+1$ instead of $a_2$.

Comment: Yes, but $a_2$ looks better than $a_1+1$ to me. @user236182

Comment: What do you know about prime gaps? Do you know that there is an $\alpha < 1$ for which it is proven that for all large enough $n$ there is a prime between $n$ and $n + n^{\alpha}$?

Comment: No I didn't know that. Is that a theorem? Is my question has any relation with that? @DanielFischer

Comment: [Yes, it's a theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds). And it implies that the answer to your question is "Yes, there are infinitely many such pairs". One can probably prove it also by simpler means. The case $a_1 = 0$ is trivial (but maybe $0$ is not considered a natural number here), the case $a_1 = 1$ is implied by Bertrand's postulate (which became Chebyshev's theorem). But it's probably not easy to give an elementary proof.

Comment: Take $a_{2}=a_{1}+1$. $a_{1}<p/q<a_{1}+1$ iff $q*a_{1}<p<q*a_{1}+q$ iff $0<p<q$ for infinitely primes $p, q$. But this is trivial by Euclid's statement of infinite primes.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you please write an answer demonstrating a proof using all those theorems you mentioned? @DanielFischer

Comment: @DanielFischer I think that Prime Number Theorem will easily imply this. If this is considered as non-elementary, then I have to think about something else.

Comment: @i707107 You're right (for values of "easily" that aren't confined to "trivially"). Whether or not the PNT counts as elementary, it's a tool whose use seems adequate for this problem.

Comment: Actually, by PNT, we can prove that {p/q : p, q primes} is dense in positive real numbers.

Comment: You can derive this from known [inequalities for the $n$th prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $a_1$ and $a_2$, I'll use $a$ and $a+1$. We get:
$$a<\dfrac{p}{q}<a+1$$
$$a\cdot q < p < (a+1)\cdot q$$
$$(a+1)\cdot q - a\cdot q\geq1$$
Since:
$$\pi(n)\sim \dfrac{n}{\log{n}}$$
We get:
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}(a+1)\cdot q - a\cdot q=\dfrac{(a+1)\cdot q}{\log{a}+\log{q}}-\dfrac{a\cdot q}{\log{a}+\log{q}}\geq 1$$
simplified:
$$\dfrac{q}{\log{a}+\log{q}}\geq 1$$
So:
$$\log{a}\leq q-\log{q}$$
And then it isn't too hard to find $q$ and after that $p$. So heuristically your statement is true.

Example:
$a=10000$
Okay, we have $\log{a}=\log{10000}\approx9.515$
The first prime $q$ for which $9.515\leq q-\log{q}$, is $13$. We plug it into the inequality:
$$13000<p<130013$$
and we find $p=13001$

Another example to really show it works for large values of $a$:
$a=1000000000$, gives $q=29$, gives $p=29000000009$

Comment: Thanks this was helpful and also I understood the heuristic insight you  demonstrated, I took this answer as somewhat useful.